# Do I need to set local variables to NULL after usage

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Do I need to set local variables to `null` after usage , for garbage collector, to collect those local variables ?

Comment: It is important for specific situations, like implementing your own collections, etc. In a standart case you should refrain from it. For more information read book "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the garbage collector automatically detects local variables that are no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no need to. Local variables aka method variables  which places on stack vanishes when we exit the local scope.